# Inserting one record at a time to multiple tables from a table

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, oracle

I have one flat MAIN_TABLE. I need to insert the records from this table to multiple TABLES.

eg.

```
MAIN_TABLE
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5

PARENT1_TABLE
PT1_ID(PK), col1,col2

PARENT2_TABLE
PT2_ID(PK), col3,col4

PARENT2_CHILD_TABLE
P2C_ID(PK), PT2_ID(FK), col5, col6
```

so on.

The goal is, I have to move the record from that flat MAIN_TABLE to the relational structured, I defined above.

Any help would be highly appreciated?

Thank you

Comment: You have this tagged as both oracle, sql-server and mysql, you need to support all platforms with the same solution?

Comment: what is preventing you from running "insert into ... select ..." 4 times ?

Answer (score 7):

In Oracle you can do [Multi-Table inserts](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2125362).
Create a dummy error logging table

```
create global temporary table err_dump
  (ORA_ERR_NUMBER$   NUMBER,
  ORA_ERR_MESG$     VARCHAR2(2000),
  ORA_ERR_ROWID$    UROWID(4000),
  ORA_ERR_OPTYP$    VARCHAR2(2),
  ORA_ERR_TAG$      VARCHAR2(2000));
```

Then add a unique key on (col1,col2) for parent1 and (col3,col4) for parent2.
Use the multi-table insert to load into the two parent tables. The LOG ERRORS INTO clause will mean that any duplicates going into parent tables will be kicked out.

```
INSERT ALL
      INTO parent1_table (pt1_id, col1,col2)
      VALUES (rn, col1,col2)
      LOG ERRORS INTO err_dump REJECT LIMIT 99999999
      INTO parent2_table (pt2_id, col3, col4)
      VALUES (rn, col3, col4)
      LOG ERRORS INTO err_dump REJECT LIMIT 99999999
   SELECT rownum rn, col1, col2, col3, col4
   FROM MAIN_TABLE;
```

Finally, do a select from MAIN, joined to parent1_table and parent2_table to get the new PKs, and that is a simple insert into  PARENT2_CHILD_TABLE

Answer (score 2):

If this was in SQL Server you could create a view of your `MAIN_TABLE`, then write an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the view. That way, as you `INSERT` a record into your `MAIN_TABLE` view, your trigger can parse it into your child tables. [Link goodness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089.aspx).

Comment: MAIN_TABLE already has data on it. I need to move that data into relational structure tables

Comment: Wow, never heard of `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` before. What a great way to baffle co-workers!

Comment: You could create a proxy table with the same schema, create the view and trigger on top of that, then use the BCP cmd with a bulk insert. Here are some other options: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3507171/Transferring-Data-from-One-Table-to-Another.htm

Comment: Actually, using a trigger is not allowed.